# How can I pick multiple dates in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, datepicker

I am trying to implement the multi select date picker in flutter, How can I implement the same in flutter application?

Answer (score 0):

Try this https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_datepicker/versions/19.2.60
this will solve your problem.